# Netapp ONTAP 7.3 - Upgrade gotchas?

Tags: netapp, ontap

So ONTAP 7.3.2 just became GD.

- Has anyone taken the plunge -- GA or GD alike?
- What platform are you running?
- What are your licensed features -- NFS, CIFS, iSCSI, FC, Multistore, API, etc?
- Any gotchas to report from in-the-field?

Answer (score 2):

We have upgraded a FAS2020 and FAS2050 from 7.2.5.1 to 7.3.2GD.

Features we have are

- NFS
- iSCSI
- FC
- SnapMirror / SnapRestore

The best benefits of this upgrade is that :

1. Aggregates are bigger on the 2020 (now 16TB)
2. Parity disks are no longer counted in the total data size of an aggregate!
3. DeDupe limits have doubled for both the 2020 and 2050

Only issue we had was that the firmware updates on the shelves took longer than they should have.

My only advice is you'll need at least 3-4% free space on each aggregate - further details can be found in the [release notes](http://now.netapp.com/NOW/knowledge/docs/ontap/rel732/html/ontap/rnote/frameset.html)

Answer (score 1):

7.3 has been a pretty bad release for us. Our configs are really simple - clustered CIFS and NFS, nothing else.

We hit loads of TOE bugs in 7.3.1 - had to upgrade to a patch release.

We hit a bug to do with async NLM in 7.3.2 (only affects Mac and FreeBSD apparently)

Now waiting for 7.3.3.